# Heatmap of regression lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, bayesian

Suppose I run a bayesian simple linear regression. I would like to visualise the results by plotting multiple regression lines based on the posterior distributions of a (intercept) and b (slope). I am wondering how to display the results in a heatmap-like style or alternatively use transparency to avoid overlapping.  Here's one simple ggplot approach.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)

N = 1000
x = 1:80
a = rnorm(N,10,3)
b = rnorm(N,5,2)

y = vector("list",length=N)
for(i in 1:N) {y[[i]] = a[i]+b[i]*x}


df = data.frame(x=rep(x,N),y=unlist(y))
df$f = rep(1:N,each=80)

(plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y,group=f)) + 
  geom_jitter(alpha=1/30,width=5,col="blue") + theme_classic())
```

Are there better ways to do this? It would be nice if the colour would change depending on the amount of overlapping (as it is in heatmaps).

Comment: I think you have a typo: `df$f = rep(1:N,each=80)`

Comment: Thanks! Corrected it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not do a line plot with samples from the posterior

```
g = ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line(alpha=1/50,col="grey",aes(group=f)) + 
  theme_classic()
```

You then then add a darker line for the posterior expection

```
g + stat_summary(geom="line", fun.y=mean, color="black", lwd=1)
```

To give

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another way that you could do this is through the `stat_density_2d` function with `ggplot2`. There are a variety of ways to do this.  Using your `df`...

As a heatmap

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y=y))+
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")+
  stat_summary(geom="line", fun.y=mean, color = "white",lwd=1)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image: heatmap]

Conversely, you could use points as well.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y=y))+
  stat_density_2d(aes(size = ..density..), geom = "point", contour = FALSE)+
  stat_summary(geom="line", fun.y=mean, color = "white",lwd=1)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image: point density]

Comment: creative and beautiful